# LateInitializationError... has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

Wondering if anyone can help with the
LateInitializationError: Field'_user@582204964' has not been initialized. when running on the emulator in android studio.

Briefly, I am absolutely new to Flutter and dart. I have been using a tutorial to work along however, unfortunately, a lot of the code has been deprecated and there is no update to the course tutorial. In which case I have been finding the new "methods" and wording to be able to continue with the course and so far so good. However I am stumped at this point with the above error message.

I have put the code that i think is the offending one and hope that someone can point me in the right direction. please take it easy on me as i said I am new and learning to navigate taking baby steps.

thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker/app/sign_in/sign_in_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  late var _user;

  void _updateUser (User user){
    initUser().whenComplete((){
      setState(() {});
    });
setState(() {
  // _user = user;
});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_user == null){
    return SignInPage(
      onSignIn: _updateUser,
    );
  }
  return Container(); // Temporary placeholder for homepage
  }
}

initUser() {
}
```

Comment: `late` means you promise the compiler that you are never going to request the value of the variable before it has been given a value. But in `build` doing exactly that by asking if `_user == null` by reading the value of `_user` before you have ever given the variable any value. This means you broke your own promise to the compiler. Since the application can no longer trust you, it crashes your application (and friendship).

Comment: @julemand101 beautiful explaination!

Comment: replace ` late var _user;` with `User? user`. does it solve?

Comment: @julemand101 the explanation is terrific . the only reason late is in there is that android studio actually recomended it and put it there. I assumed that in that case it must have been correct. Having read your explanation now i have rekindled my friendship with my application by changing it to User? user as suggested by Yeasin Sheikh.

Answer (score 0):

You have comment out the line in which you were initializing the value of user inside the setState((){}) function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).